# std::distance provide a past the end index when given an iterator returned by std::find

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, std

This is an exempt piece of code I'm currently working on.
`std::find` seems to do the job as expected, however `std::distance` always returns 3, i tried various configurations or there is something wrong with the `it` in front of `std::find`.
I would like to have the correct index of the array depending how the strings ends.

`it` prints an address.

```
const auto b = {"uF", "nF", "pF"}; 

std::string str("1.0uF");  // test string.   
//std::string str("1.0nF");  // test string.
//std::string str("1.0pF");  // test string.

auto it = std::find(b.begin(), b.end(), str);
debug  << "b has type: " << typeid(it).name() << '\n';
// b has type:  PKPKc
debug << "index: " << std::distance(b.begin(), it) <<'\n'; //*(*it) << '\n';
```

Comment: Note: `const auto b = {"uF", "nF", "pF"};` is making an `initializer_list`, not an array

Comment: `find` is not working correctly.  `typeid(it).name()` will always have the same value as a type never changes.  its values that change.  you need to compare `it` against `end()`

Comment: `find` didn't find `1.0uf` since it doesn't exist so the end iterator is returned which is 3 from the start. https://godbolt.org/z/7hsEeWdM9

Comment: A few more notes about `typeid(it).name()`. `name` doesn't guarantee you'll get a human readable name. It doesn't even guarantee that two different types won't have the same name. It's not very useful. If you just want to take a peek, you can often use an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) or [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to reveal what type was actually inferred.

Comment: @NathanOliver i wanted to see what type it was to see if the action I'm doing is applicable.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm not all the time occupied with C++.

Comment: @user4581301 I use Qt creator.

Comment: I changed the tag to C++11, since C11 is a completely different language.

Comment: @NaturalDemon If you use Qt creator most likely you're using GCC, which is compatible with C++20 if you add the `-std=c++20` compiler flag ;)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot the project file `*.pro` says: `CONFIG += c++17` or where should i put that?

Comment: Oh! Just change it to `CONFIG += c++20`. If your stack supports it, it should just work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255213/discussion-between-naturaldemon-and-guillaume-racicot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::find()` uses `operator==` as comparator, so the string needs to be an exact match for the element to be found.

What you're looking for is `std::find_if()`, eg:

```
auto ends_with(std::string const& str, std::string const& suffix) -> bool {
    if (str.length() < suffix.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    return std::equal(suffix.rbegin(), suffix.rend(), str.rbegin());
}


auto main() -> int {
    using namespace std::literals; // for the 's' suffix

    const auto b = std::array{"uF"s, "nF"s, "pF"s}; 

    std::string str("1.0uF");  // test string.   
    //std::string str("1.0nF");  // test string.
    //std::string str("1.0pF");  // test string.

    // always std::string::iterator
    auto it = std::find_if(
        b.begin(), b.end(),
        [&](std::string const& e) {
            return ends_with(str, e);
        }
    );

    if (it != b.end()) {
        // found    
        debug << "index: " << std::distance(b.begin(), it) <<'\n'; //*(*it) << '\n';
    } else {
        // not found, distance is one past the end
    }
}
```

As you might notice, `auto` doesn't make the types deduced at runtime. All types in C++, whether you use `auto` or not, are all fixed as if you had written them by hand. You only need to write the correct logic for your needs.

Only the array might be confusing since it's deducing `std::initializer_list` by default. Using `std::array` fixes that.

Comment: This should probably be using `std::array<std::string_view, 3>` instead of working with raw pointers. That could also be done via `std::array{"uF"sv, "nF"sv, "pF"sv}`

Comment: @JanSchultke most likely, but I wanted to do the most minimal changes.

Comment: `// b has type:  PKPKc` may or may not be different now, but it isn't clear why OP looked at it anyway.

Comment: Also you can use `std::ranges::find_if` if you're relying on C++20's `std::basic_string::ends_with`. Or if you aren't relying on C++20 in this answer, then it would be good to provide an alternative for older versions.

Comment: @JanSchultke I could have used it but I didn't wanted to involve ranges.

Comment: Thnx, but i get this: error: No member named 'ends_with' in 'std::basic_string<char>' in QT creator, albeit having "<string>" included, but that member is not included in the context menu when adding a point. if i change "std::string str = ("1.0uF"); " to auto, i get another error. i peeked the C++ reference and it should be ok.

Comment: it's a C20 thing and i got C11.

Comment: @NaturalDemon it's rather trivial to implement as a free function. I would also recommend adding the `c++11` tag to your question if you want answers only for older standard if you are constrained them as C++11 is twelve years old at this point, and I usually assume C++20 in my answers.

Comment: @NaturalDemon I added an implementation of ends_with and made the answer C++11 compatible

Comment: Cool, it works and does what i want, i was looking for the header to see how it's defined, i did that once before "extracting" a newer function from a header to make it work with C11. `auto ends_with(std::string const& str, std::string const& suffix) -> bool`, the "auto" and "-> bool" to a function, never seen that before.

Comment: @NaturalDemon It's an alternative syntax to put the return type after the parameters instead of before. It is 100% equivalent, but allow better scoping when dealing with member type of a class or when implementing templates.